# Maximum of sums of unsorted array and each of a number of sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an *unsorted* array

```
A = a_1 ... a_n
```

And a set of *sorted* Arrays

```
B_i = b_i_1 ... b_i_n   # for i from 1 to $large_number
```

I would like to find the maximums from the (not yet calculated) sum arrays

```
C_i = (a_1 + b_i_1) ... (a_n + b_i_n)
```

for each `i`.

Is there a trick to do better than just calculating all the C_i and finding their maximums in O($large_number * n)?

Can we do better when we know that the `B` arrays are just shifts from an endless sequence,
e.g.

```
S = 0 1 4 9 16 ...
B_i = S[i:i+n]
```

(The above sequence has the maybe advantageous property that `(S_i - S_i-1 > S_i-1 - S_i-2)`)

Answer (score 1):

There are $large_number * n data in your first problem, so there can't be any such trick.

You can prove this with an adversary argument.  Suppose you have an algorithm that solves your problem without looking at all n * $large_number entries of b.  I'm going to pick a fixed a, namely (-10, -20, -30, ..., -10n).  The first $large_number * n - 1 the algorithm looks at an entry b_(i,j), I'll answer that it's 10j, for a sum of zero.  The last time it looks at an entry, I'll answer that it's 10j+1, for a sum of 1.

If $large_number is Omega(n), your second problem requires you to look at n * $large_number entries of S, so it also can't have any such trick.

However, if you specify S, there may be something.  And if $large_number <= n/2 (or whatever it is), then, all of the entries of S must be sorted, so you only have to look at the last B.

Answer (score 0):

If we don't know anything I don't it's possible to do better than O($large_number * n)

However - If it's just shifts of an endless sequence we can do it in `O($large_number + n)`:
We calculate B_0 ןמ `O($large_number)`.
Than B_1 = (B_0 - S[0]) + S[n+1]
And in general: `B_i = (B_i-1 - S[i-1]) + S[i-1+n]`.
So we can calculate all the other entries and the max in `O(n)`.

This is for a general sequence - if we have some info about it, it might be possible to do better.

Answer (score 0):

we know that the `B` arrays are just shifts from an endless sequence,
e.g.

```
S = 0 1 4 9 16 ...
B_i = S[i:i+n]
```

You can easily calculate S[i:i+n] as (sum of squares from 1 to i+n) - (sum of squares from 1 to  i-1)

See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers

With the provided example, S1 = 0, S2 = 1, S3 = 4...
Let f(n) = SUM of Si for i=1 to n = (n-1)(n)(2n-1)/6
B_i = f(i+n) - f(i-1)

You then add SUM(A) to each sum.

Another approach is to calculate the difference between B_i and B_(i-1):
That would be: S[i:i+n] - S[i-1:i+n-1] = S(i+n) - S(i-1)

That way, you can just calculate the difference of the sums of each array with the previous one. In my understanding, since Ci = SUM(Bi)+SUM(A), SUM(A) becomes a constant that is irrelevant in finding the maximum.

Comment: I don't think this answers my problem. If you think so, might you elaborate?

Comment: See revised answer. Maybe you should have posted this question in a well formatted way to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You got the definition of C_i wrong. `C_i_j = A_j + B_i_j`!

Comment: Hence C_i=(sum for j A_j) + (sum for j of B_i_j)